# How the SQL join actually works?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, computer-science

Suppose I have two table `Gardners table` and `Plantings table`.

[image]

Suppose my query is:

```
SELECT gid, first_name, last_name, pid, gardener_id, plant_name 
FROM Gardners
INNER JOIN Plantings
ON gid = gardener_id
```

I want to know how exactly it works internally?

As per my understanding in every `join` condition:

- Each row from `Gardner Table` will be compared with each row of `Plantings Table`. If the condition is matched then it will print out. Is my understanding correct?

In terms of program if you think:

```
for i in [Gardners Table]:
    for j in [Plantings Table]:
         if i.id == j.garderner id:
            print <>
```

Now suppose if you query is something like:

```
User(uid,uname,ucity,utimedat)
Follows(uid,followerid) // uid and followerid are pointing to `uid` of `User`.

SELECT U.uid, U.uname FROM User U1 JOIN Follows F,User U2 WHERE 
  F.followerid = U2.uiddate AND U2.ucity = 'D'
```

How the join condition will work internally here? Is it equivalent to:

```
for i in [USER]:
        for j in [Follows]:
            for k in [USER]:
             if condition:
                print <>
```

Comment: Your understanding appears to be correct.  But I would clean up your query to use aliases so that it is clear to which table each column belongs.

Comment: Could you see my update please!

Comment: Looking for algorithms which will be used for selection and joining. Could you elaborate on that sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example with `Gardners table` and `Plantings table` is correct. But example with `users` not so obvious.

I think that what you want to get is user followers from some city.

Assuming correct query is:

```
SELECT U1.uid, U2.uname
FROM User U1 
  JOIN Follows F ON U1.uid = F.uid
  JOIN User U2 ON F.followerid = U2.uid
WHERE U2.ucity = 'D'
```

Then in pseudo code it'll look like this:

```
for i in [User Table]:
  for j in [Follows Table]:
    if i.uid = j.uid:
      for k in [User Table]:
        if j.followerid = k.uid and k.city = 'D':
          print <>
```

SQL Fiddle for this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/caeb1e/5

There is a very good picture of how joins actually works can be found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

[image: SQL Joins]

Comment: Could you describe where I am wrong with `Users`?  I know different SQL join, so your diagram is not helping me. I want to understand internally how things work!

Comment: Looking for algorithms which will be used for `selection` and `joining`. Could you speak about that please!

Comment: Could you please add a reference whence you got this diagram.  Also, I think his pseudo-code in the OP actually explains the output better than a diagram.

Comment: @python you select `U.uid, U.uname`, but you have 2 tables `U1` and `U2` from which one of them you want to get the data?

Comment: @YuriTkachenko Thanks! Very helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

In your second query, it's not clear what you're trying to do exactly as the syntax is erroneous; but if I were to guess, it seems like your intention is to join User U1 with a sub query of (implicit) join between Followers F and User U2.

If my guess is correct, the query would properly look more like this:

```
SELECT U1.uid, U1.uname 
FROM User U1 JOIN 
  (SELECT U2.uid 
   FROM Followers F,User U2 
   WHERE F.followerid = U2.uiddate AND U2.ucity = 'D') T 
WHERE u1.uid = T.uid
```

Which is not a 'best practice' way of writing the query either (you should use explicit joins, there's no need for a sub-query but you can just join three times, and so on)
But I wrote it this way to keep it closest to your original query.

And if my guess is correct, then your pseudo code would be more like:

```
for u2 in [User 2 where condition]:
        for f in [Follows]:
           if f.uid == u2.uid
             SELECT uid AS T
               for u1 in [User 1]:
                 if u1.uid == T.uid:
                   print <>
```

However, it's not a fully explained interpretation, because one key to understanding SQL is to think more in 'set' of data being filtered, rather than sequential selection of objects of data, because SQL does operations based on the set of data, which one might not be used to. 
So a number of the above steps will be executed in one go, instead of sequential. But other than that, you should look towards the answer given by Yuri Tkachenko above, in how to view joins - and then the internals will come second when writing correct joins.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're understanding is correct if you are only talking on a join not on the other join eg: Inner, Outer like in SQL